# Get HTML Source For Desktop Page In Android

Tags: android, html, desktop-application

I am writing an Android app to get the source of a few web pages, then extract information out of them. I have my method to get the source of a web page for the mobile version of a page below, but I need help to get the source of the desktop version please.

```
 private static String getURLSource(String address) throws IOException
{
    String inputLine = "";
    String urlSource = "";
    URL url = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    InputStream iS = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(iS);
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);
    inputLine = bR.readLine();
    while(inputLine != null)
    {
        urlSource += inputLine;
        inputLine = bR.readLine();
    }
    bR.close();
    return urlSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add user agent to some desktop UA I think, something like:
`conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.11");`

EDIT: Complete tested code:

```
    class RetreiveUrlSourceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... address) {
        String inputLine = "";
        String urlSource = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.11");
            InputStream iS = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(iS);
            BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);
            inputLine = bR.readLine();
            while(inputLine != null)
            {
                urlSource += inputLine;
                android.util.Log.d("getURLSource", inputLine);
                inputLine = bR.readLine();
            }
            bR.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlSource;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String urlSource) {
    }
}
```

and then call:

```
RetreiveUrlSourceTask task = new RetreiveUrlSourceTask();
task.execute("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/");
```

Comment: When I put that line in my code and write the source to file, the file shows as empty.

Comment: So changing from "no user agent at all" to the UA above, makes file empty? Could you try other desktop User-Agent, please?

Comment: Also tried "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0" which also makes file empty.

Comment: The spec says that if there is an error, you should " Use getErrorStream() to read the error response. " (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). If that is also empty, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: You can also try if this example works for you: http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2011/11/android-setting-user-agent-for-url.html

Comment: That example worked for me, thank you for your help.